# How to get detailed errors from ModelState asp.net web api identity

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity-2

I have a register form with asp.net web api 2 identity.

This is my register function:

```
// POST api/Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return GetErrorResult(result);
        }

        try
        {
            ...send email
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

If `ModelState` is not valide it returns something like this:

[image]

How can I get this detailed error?
I'm looking for a way to dynamically get all detailed errors from ModelState.
I'm not sure if I should do it on the Web api or in javascript when I get the response.

Comment: Do you mean the error at `data.modelState["model.Password"][0]` ?

Comment: Yes, but each time it's in a different place, how can I get dynamically all detailed errors?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Thank you, it helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing the following function on my AccountController.
It loops through the errors on the `ModelState`, adds them to a list and then it loops through the list and adds them to the `ModelState`.

```
public void SetCustomError()
    {
        var errors = new List<string>();
        foreach (var state in ModelState)
        {
            foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
            {
                errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("CustomError", error);
        }
    }
```

And then on my javascript I handled it like this:

```
function showError(jqXHR) {
    if (jqXHR) {      
        jsonValue = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
        if (!jsonValue.modelState["customError"] == undefined) {
            $("#error").text(jsonValue.modelState["customError"][0]);
        }
        else {
            $("#error").text(jsonValue.modelState[""][0]);
        }
        $("#modalError").dialog();
    }
}
```